# How to check the type of a parameter passed to a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to make sure that a parameter that is passed to a function is an element and not a number or a string so my program does not crash?

```js
function myFunction(element){ 
  console.log(element.style.color)
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: You probably want to check more than it not being a number or a string.

Comment: in 2020 you can refer it as `element?.style?.color` . that is the simplest possible way and pretty safe of crashes

Comment: @Andrei good suggestion, but that doesn't make it safe.

Comment: You can get some interesting information from `param.__proto__.toString()` and `"" + param.constructor` and `param.tagName` — you can also check if several attributes exist that all Elements will have and (most) other things won't.

Comment: Use TypeScript? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're looking for [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement):

```js
function myFunction(element) {
  if (element instanceof HTMLElement) {
    console.log(element.style.color)
  }
}
```